# SQL question using Cursor - case study on taking First Transaction

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Recently, I am working on SQL.

A basic yet ambiguous question I have as follow:
given a table A, which includes transactions information such as Transaction Number (TRX_NO), Customer Name (CUS_NAME), Customer Code (CUS_CODE) and Transaction time (TRX_TIME). Noted that for every transaction, there will be a record. For instance, when Mary goes to the shop on 20201024, 20201025, 20201031, then there are three records hold in this table.

With this in mind, if either using temp_table or cursor, how can I insert all first time data to another table B?

A more specific example, if the current table A stores three records of Mary, table B should hold the record of 20201024. In  what way can I achieve this?

I have tried using cursor, but seems not a good try:

```
  DECLARE var_VIP   VARCHAR2(20);
        
        CURSOR cur_FIRST IS 
                SELECT A.CUS_CODE 
                FROM TABLEA A
                ORDER BY CUS_CODE, TRX_DATE, TRX_TIME;
                
        --OPEN AND START CURSOR
        BEGIN
        OPEN cur_FIRST;
        LOOP
        FETCH cur_FIRST INTO var_VIP;      
        EXIT WHEN cur_FIRST%NOTFOUND;
              INSERT INTO TABLEB B
              (SELECT* 
              FROM TABLEA A
              ORDER BY TRX_DATE, TRX_TIME);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur_FIRST;
```

Thanks a lot for help!!!

Comment: Is your DBMS Oracle or SQL Server? The syntax suggests the second one.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Oh sorry that I did not recognise it. I am using PL/SQL developer

Comment: PL/SQL developer for connecting to MySQL?

Comment: you removed the tag `oracle`, but didn't tag the related DBMS.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for reminding.

Comment: you're welcome but I didn't mean the `database` :) , but the brand for DBMS such as `SQL Server`, `My SQL`, `Maria DB`, `SQL` (Structured Query Language) as it refers is just a language.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks a lot for telling me. It seems like I made a big mistake! Now I have changed the style. It would be nice if you can help me to check with.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Oh I see. I am so new to the SQL world... Yet, thanks for all reminders and sharing of your knowledge

Comment: [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) is a desktop tool for working with Oracle. Also, [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) and  [PL/SQL](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/plsql.html) are two different things.

Comment: Aside from all of the provided technical solutions to your question, I would like to suggest that there is no need to do this at all.  In fact, there is a very good reason _not_ to do it.  There is simply no reason to create a second table to hold a subset of the first table.  This goes against all principles of rdbms design. Do not create duplicated data. If you need to report 'first visit', you can always select it from the primary table when needed.  You could even create a view to pre-define that selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote down a shorter example which will help you understand the concept.

```
   --create the tables
    CREATE TABLE TABLEA (CUS_CODE INTEGER,
                         TRX_DATE DATE);
    
    
    CREATE TABLE TABLEB (CUS_CODE INTEGER,
                         TRX_DATE DATE);
    
    --insert some values
    insert into TABLEA values (1, SYSDATE);
    insert into TABLEA values (1, SYSDATE+1);
    insert into TABLEA values (1, SYSDATE+2);
    
    insert into TABLEA values (2, SYSDATE);
    insert into TABLEA values (2, SYSDATE+1);
    insert into TABLEA values (3, SYSDATE+2);
```

The procedure code:

```
  DECLARE
        CURSOR cur_FIRST IS 
                SELECT A.CUS_CODE, min(A.TRX_DATE) as TRX_DATE
                FROM TABLEA A
                GROUP BY CUS_CODE;
         
         var_VIP  cur_FIRST%rowtype;      
        --OPEN AND START CURSOR
    BEGIN
        OPEN cur_FIRST;
        LOOP
          FETCH cur_FIRST INTO var_VIP;      
          EXIT WHEN cur_FIRST%NOTFOUND;
              INSERT INTO TABLEB VALUES (VAR_vip.CUS_CODE, VAR_VIP.TRX_DATE);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur_FIRST;
    END;
```

And check the result:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEB;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I am a little but confuse on the point about %rowtype. Sorry but may you explain more about what do you want to achieve through %rowtype  please. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this useful link: [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/rowtype_attribute.htm#LNPLS01342)…...

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor solution is a little confusing, I can see what you might be trying to do but it's just unnecessary. You don't need to use explicit cursors and fetch them line by line, an `insert` statement can use a `select` clause.

Your problem is usually solved with analytic functions, this way you can rank all rows for each different customer. BTW I don't know why you'd have a column called `TRX_TIME` as well as `TRX_DATE`, in Oracle you have one date datatype which stores both the date and time components. If we assume that `trx_date` is a date and has been populated with the time information:

```
insert into tableb (cus_code, trx_no, trx_date, cus_name)
select cus_code, trx_no, trx_date, cus_name
from (
 select cus_code, trx_no, trx_date, cus_name, row_number() over (partition by cus_code order by trx_date) rn
 from   tablea a
)
where rn = 1
```

Note how I'm also listing my columns explicitly in the insert statement too and not relying on the order of columns in the table (or that no other columns have been added without me knowing).

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your info about rownumber(). I have never heard of it before. As for date and time, actually, I was thinking about to create a string storage instead of date in oracle, so I have them. Thanks a lot for solution!